# What does this lambda function do

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I was looking through the questions of sorting dictionary by values in python and came across this answer.

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

However, i do not understand what this function exactly does and how does it even help to sort the dictionary by returning a list of tuples or anything for that matter

Comment: The `lambda` itself is pretty straight forward; I think your question is really how `sorted` *uses* the `key` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a sample dictionary.

```
d = {'e': 1, 'd': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 4, 'a': 5}
```

`items` will return the items in the dictionary as a key, value tuple pair.

```
>>> d.items()
[('a', 5), ('c', 3), ('b', 4), ('e', 1), ('d', 2)]
```

`sorted' on its own will simply sort the keys in the dictionary:

```
>>> sorted(d)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

'sorted(d.items())` will sort the dictionary in ascending order by the keys:

```
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('d', 2), ('e', 1)]
```

Passing the lambda function, however, uses the second item in the pair (i.e. the value) as the basis for the sort. `x` represents a tuple pair (e.g. ('b', 4), and x[1] would represent 4 in this case).:

```
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
[('e', 1), ('d', 2), ('c', 3), ('b', 4), ('a', 5)]
```

The sort order can also be reversed:

```
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('d', 2), ('e', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This lambda accepts a list/tuple as an argument and returns the element on the 2nd place: `x[1]`

It can be used to sort lists, for example:

```
[['b',2], ['a',4], ['c',1]]
```

The sort will use the lambda expression to extract the second element in each list: 2,4,1 and will sort the lists according to this element.

So the output of this example will be in our case:

```
[['c', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 4]]
```

**Comment**: this same sorting could be applied to any sequence of lists with *more* than 2 elements!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a dictionary that you want sorted into a list.

For example

```
{'x': 5, 'y': 6}.items()  # returns [(x, 5), (y, 6)]
```

Now you also want to ensure this output list is sorted by the values (5 and 6) - since this is not always guaranteed.

So you pass it into the `sort` function, and pass in a `lambda` which specifically indicates how you want this list sorted.

For example in your case you are sorting by the second value of each pair in the list `x[1]`, but you could also sort by the first value of each pair `x[0]`

You can also replace the lambda with a regular function:

```
def sort_key(x):
    return x[1]

sorted(d.items(), key=sort_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument `key` of the function `sorted` just allow you specify a function that accepts an item (of the list that you want to sort) and returns a value you want to sort by.

`d.items()` is a list of tuple which have two fields like this: `(dict_key, dict_value)`.

And `lambda x: x[1]` is equal to `def anonymous_func(x): return x[1]`, so in your code, the list (`d.items()`) will be sorted by field 1 (the value field of original dict).